# set a specific position as the default position in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, transform, instantiation

i need to spawn the character with other various characters like this :

```
Instantiate(Unit, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

but the problem is one of the units are a little bit down so i should make it go up a little bit so i went to the inspecter and changed the Y position from 0 to 2.36 and now i want it to be the defualt position so i can spawn the unit like every other unit .

i tried looking for it in the internet and asking CHATGPT but there is noway he would answer that.

Comment: you can forward the position as an argument. See [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well i found if you just do this:

```
    Vector3 vec3 = transform.position +  Unit.transform.position;

    Instantiate(Unit, vec3, Quaternion.identity);
```

and adjust all units positions to 0,0,0 else the wanted ones.

you can do it with just the Y value but i did it this way.

I was a little sleepy.

Answer (score 0):

For better code readability, reset all prefabs (Unit prefabs in this case) transform at Vector3.Zero (0,0,0) before instantiating them in their intended positions. The shifted one might have its position set to another value than (0,0,0).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).